# Pyrebase not successfully install in python 3.7.1

Tags: python

> Im having trouble why pyrebase cannot install, Im using Python 3.7.1 and I used this command python -m pip install pyrebase .Do you have any idea why is this happening? the error is always like this and I've already try to upgrade setup tools and cloud, see also the image below.

```
Error: Command errored out with exit status 1:
```

[File error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aI8Oj.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

simply run

```
pip3 install pyrebase4
```